# Add component to shopify slider cart using Jquery

Tags: jquery, shopify, shopify-app

I want to append a custom component to the Shopify cart slider. For example, I want to add "hello world" text above the checkout button. I don't have access to the code of the shop since I am building a Shopify app so I need to append it using Jquery.

```
    $("<h1>Hello world</h1>").insertBefore(button[name='checkout']);
```

I select the correct button somehow the jquery doesn't work with Shopify slider cart. If I want to append the text somewhere else, everything works just fine. Could you guy show me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the website link so that i can check the html element by myself? Thanks

Comment: https://brooklyn-theme-playful.myshopify.com/?_bt=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaWxpY205dmEyeDViaTEwYUdWdFpTMXdiR0Y1Wm5Wc0xtMTVjMmh2Y0dsbWVTNWpiMjBHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTEwLTE2VDExOjE5OjE2LjI1OFoiLCJwdXIiOiJwZXJtYW5lbnRfcGFzc3dvcmRfYnlwYXNzIn19--62dd4f46ed662439435097d4d4bfe1e2c4c2fa44

Comment: It seems that the cart component isn't available in the DOM util is is opened

Comment: Yeah I see that. What you have to do is. You need to customize the theme CSS code in order to append something after the checkout button. Make the Cart Drawer "display:block" and set its visibility to hidden.